# XCUITest Testing Native Callkit UI Using Springboard. How to get the caller label?

Tags: ios, swift, callkit, xcuitest, springboard

I am trying to test VOIP calling in our app. I simulate a call and I try to assert if the correct caller ID is present. However, I can't access the caller name label "Bob" using the following:

```swift
let springBoard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
XCTAssert(springBoard.staticTexts["Bob‬"].waitForExistence(timeout: 10)) // Assertion fails
```

However, if I try to access the label just below it "*** Audio…" using the same call the assertion passes:

```swift
XCTAssert(springBoard.staticTexts["*** Audio…"].waitForExistence(timeout: 10))
```

When I print out `springBoard.debugDescription` I find both "Bob" and "*** Audio…" in the accessibility hierarchy and they both are staticTexts:

[image: Debug Description]

The screen being tested:

[image: Native UI Being Tested]

How do I go about accessing "Bob" label and asserting that it's the correct caller ID?

Answer (score 1):

I met the same kind of issue. I figured it out using `NSPredicate` with a LIKE  instead of using only the name. I think hidden characters are added around the name.

```
            XCTAssert(springBoard.staticTexts.matching(NSPredicate(format: "label LIKE '*Bob*'")).firstMatch.waitForExistence(timeout: 10))
```

This works for me and should work for you as well.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This workaround could be used in some cases. However, it is not conclusive as the name we are trying to assert could be a substring of the presented name. (Ex: 'Bobby' would pass the test even though we are looking for 'Bob')

Comment: You can use `?` instead of `*` which matches only one character instead of many. So, you can use as many `?` as expected to skip hidden characters and it will still work with `Bob` but not with `Bobby`.